# Typing in a particular cell and convert it in upper case

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, text-formatting

After I typed in a cell a text value (this is in lower case), what do I need to do (after typed it), to become it as the upper case?

How do you change the case to upper case for a whole column in Google Sheets? I don't need it to do anything fancy.

Comment: sorry the title should be typing in particular cell in lower case

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I want this to become upper case just outright when I just typed in cell A2 as well when I type on the rest of the cell under that column

In that case, you need to use this script which does exactly what you want (converts all input in column A from 2nd row onwards on Sheet1).

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var sheet, sheetName, colToCapitalize;
    sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    colToCapitalize = 1;
    sheetName = 'Sheet1';
    if (sheet.getName() !== sheetName || e.range.rowStart < 2 || e.range.columnStart !== colToCapitalize || typeof e.value == 'object') return;
    e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase())
}
```

for range **Sheet1!C2:C** use:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var sheet, sheetName, colToCapitalize;
    sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    colToCapitalize = 3;
    sheetName = 'Sheet1';
    if (sheet.getName() !== sheetName || e.range.rowStart < 2 || e.range.columnStart !== colToCapitalize || typeof e.value == 'object') return;
    e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase())
}
```

Comment: yes i realized and i changed  colToCapitalize = 1; by 3 just before you wrote back as 3 is column C thanks a million and also it works great, question 1-where can i find how to learn those syntax as you wrote in the script ? 2- how can i make an apps, so this google sheet can be added as an app to an android device like a phone or table ? if possible thanks again and sorry for be bugging you

Comment: check here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: Thanks a lot , will read, it is extensive, so if i want to this google sheet to be in an android phone or table i need to create an app, the whole thing is, what do you recommend me to use to make and easy app to be installed for data entry from the mobil device, as i am so novice, there is a lot of info to read and it is confuse, maybe i can make an basic easy app for mobile device and get it from there, do u have any specific suggestion and guide at least to start a simple app from the google sheet i have already ? thanks man a lot

Comment: sorry, can't help you with that because I have no experience of building apps

Comment: Hi dear user0, no problem, i will learn little by little, but if you don't care i have another question, you know my google sheet is named "MYNEWSHEET" so i actually need to download always this google sheet as a csv, i know i can do it from the  "download As" but the problem is when i do that, the file downloaded is named then "mynewsheet*sheet1.csv", so two questions for you 1-is there a way to have at the menu a CUSTOM tab, that allow me just to click there and download the file as mynewsheet.csv" ?

Comment: 2- it is possible, instead of going to my download folder as we know it is the default folder, to another folder  in my pc ? example maybe i can send it to another drive like E:\CSV, where "CSV" it is folder, so then later i can read that csv file and append to a table(dbf file) thanks a lot man

Comment: yes, both things are doable from a technical side

Comment: it is possible  for you to indicate how to accomplish it  please ?

Comment: unfortunately no, that is beyond my skills

Answer (score 0):

- for one cell:

  ```
  =UPPER(A1)
  ```
- for the whole column:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER(A1:A))
  ```

  [image]

Comment: dear  user() i am not able to figure out, how after i type in C2 a text to make this auto to be in uppercase, i can do it manually but i just need it to be in uppercase after typed int that cell, i don't why the formula does not work on me, i know you put the formula in another different cell but i need the uppercase text to be all along down in C2, C3 and so on, always after i type in the required cell thanks